# How to extend cookie expiration CORRECTLY? Users got automatically kicked in less than an hour

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core

I am using cookies to persist authenticated users on my page

`Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc(config =>
  {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                   .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                   .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
  });

  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
  {
    AccessDeniedPath = "/Accounts/Forbidden/",
    AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    LoginPath = "/Account/Login/",
    LogoutPath = "/Account/Login/",
    ExpiresTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10)
  });
}
```

`AccountController.cs`

```
public async Task<IActionController> Login(UserVm model)
{
  if(_repo.ValidateCredentials(model.UserName, model.Password))
  {
    var user = _repo.FindUser(model.UserName);
    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
    if(model.RememberLogin)
    {
      props = new AuthenticationProperties
      {
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DataTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(10))
      };
    }

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(user), CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props);

    return Redirect("~/");
  }
}
```

It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore1x#absolute-cookie-expiration), if I enable `IsPersistent`, it'll override the `ExpireTimeSpan`on `CookieAuthenticationOptions` So, I did. I want to extend my cookies to 10days. But it seems that my users got automatically kicked out in less than an hour. I noticed this when I published my application live on IIS. Is this something to do with my server?

How can I extend my cookies expiration CORRECTLY so my users won't be kicked out? I'm using netcoreapp1.1

Comment: What does the `Set-Cookie` response header show in [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: Where are you hosting your application? IIS? Azure App Service? These will stop your application/recycle the application pools on idle and memory pressure. By default ASP.NET Core doesn't persist encryption keys, so after the app restarts all cookies and logins are invalidated. You need to use the data protection configuration provider to persist the encryption key so they can survive a app restart